# Ruby multithreading print stdout

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm implementing a network in Ruby and we're having some issues with printing while multithreading. We have two threads which are listeners, so they're always on (like a server implementation would do). We want to print to stdout with both of these threads, but it seems like only one can print at a time.

For example, we have the "driver" which parses a file and spawns the threads and we wanted to print some of the information we parsed from the file before we spawned the thread. The thread which is spawned has some stuff we want to print to stdout, just for debugging purposes. However the only stuff we see when we run the program is the print from the thread which we spawned. All we're doing is starting the thread with a given function and joining on it. What are we doing wrong here?

```
def populateFromFile()


    file = File.open('filename.csv')
    while( (line = file.gets) != nil)
        #do processing and populate the neighbors array

    end
    #When we do not start the thread below, we definitely see this output
    $neighbors.each {|neighbor| puts neighbor.to_s}
end

def listenerFunc
    while(true)
        command = STDIN.gets
        #when this thread is started, we ONLY see this output.
        puts command
    end
end

t1 = Thread.new{listenerFunc}
t1.join
```

Comment: Could you povide some code example?

Comment: Code is worth 10,000 words. What did you try? A description of the code doesn't tell us nearly as much as what you actually wrote. Please read "[ask]".

Comment: I just added the code in question.

Comment: What Ruby runtime do you use (MRI, JRuby, ...)?

Comment: not terribly sure, but we use irb, ruby version 1.9.3. Does that answer your question?